# Object Not Resolved to a Local Variable (Java)

Tags: java, object, search

I'm writing a Java program to process each state of a search graph, but can't seem to create instances of State inside one of my loops.

The program takes numbers from a file, line by line, and converts each number into a `State` object, however I'm getting an error `State cannot be resolved to a variable`

```
public class ABSrch {

static HashMap<Integer, State> states = new HashMap<Integer, State>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("D:\\Stuff\\TextExample.txt");
    int level = 0, depthBound = 0, stateNumber = 0;

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

        depthBound = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().split(" ")[1]);

        s.close(); s = new Scanner(file);

        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

            if(level >= 0 && level <= 7) {
                if(level == 0) tokens = line.split(" |7");
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                State parent = new State(false,0,0,null); //error: State not resolved to variable

            level++;
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
    }
}
}
```

State class:

```
public class State {
private boolean max;
private int name, value;
private State parent;
private ArrayList<State> children;

public State(boolean max, int name, int value, State parent) {
    this.max = max;
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
    children = new ArrayList<State>();
}

public boolean isMax() { if(max == true) return true; else return false; }
public void setMax(boolean max) { this.max = max; }

public int getValue() { return value; }
public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }

public int getName() { return name; }
}
```

Comment: What package are both of these classes in?

Comment: Oh, it means you can't declare a variable inside a for loop.  Move the declaration outside.

Comment: Always use braces, even for a single statement. And ask yourself: what's the point of creating a State if you create it and then forget about it? What's the point of a map if you don't store anything inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                State parent = new State(false,0,0,null);
```

You cannot have initialization inside for loop without braces. It counts as **local variable declaration** and is not allowed in Java loops. This is to prevent you from using references which are valid only during object initialization. After iterating over the loop, references to the object created in previous iteration would be lost so garbage collector would soon destroy this objects.

This, hovewer, should work (but it is a bad practice and probably won't do what you expect from it):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                  State parent = new State(false,0,0,null);
}
```

Joshua Bloch in his book [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com) provides an excellent explanation:

> A local variable declaration looks like a statement but technically
>   speaking is not; it is a local variable declaration statement [JLS
>   14.4]. The syntax of the language does not allow a local variable declaration statement as the statement repeated by a for, while, or do
>   loop [JLS 14.12-14]. A local variable declaration can appear only as a
>   statement directly within a block. (A block is a pair of curly braces
>   and the statements and declarations contained within it.)